# Are there any modern alternatives to the RIFF file format standard?

Tags: wav, file-format, riff

I like the RIFF standards but I don't like that file length is limited to 4GB. Is there a good modern file format standard for storing binary data that is like RIFF?

I see that for long WAV files Adobe programs will essentially just ignore the file length bytes, but if I am making a new file format it seems weird to include bytes only to NOT use them. If RIFF generally frowned upon in modern formats or no?